# With Bootstrap 4, how to build a layout that has a div when the device is large?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid

I'm looking to build a layout/grid with Bootstrap 4 that is similar to the screenshots attached.

Notice how on the large device screens, there is a column on the left which on smaller device is removed and the main column is re-centered.

source URL: https://projects.invisionapp.com/d/login

How can this be done with Bootstrap 4?

[image: large device]

[image: medium device]

[image: small device]

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, Bootstrap 4 has a lot of abilities with regards to Media Queries. I'd start by taking a look here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

I think people are down voting this because it's so general. For someone with your reputation, I'd stick to the guidelines that got you there. For more general questions in the future, use a reddit or something... Just my advice.

Comment: thanks code4fun, I have a basic concept working but usually like asking here as I end up learning better ways to solve problems. As a sole developer, it's the only way I learn and become a better engineer.

Comment: For sure! I personally can appreciate that. I just know in my experience with my main developer account, the community as a whole seems to frown upon questions like these :/